# AJAX Call to PHP File for HTML Form Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a login-form created using HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class= "form-header">Login</div>
    <div class= "error-message" id= "login-error-exists"></div>
        <form action= "login.php" method= "POST" onsubmit= "loginCheckIncorrect()">
            <div class= "form-field">
                <div class= "form-text">
                    username:
                </div>
                <input type= "text" class= "login-textbox" id= "login-login-username" name= "loginLoginUsername">
            </div>
            <div class= "form-field">
                <div class= "form-text">
                    password:
                </div>
                <input type= "password" class= "login-textbox" id= "login-login-password" name= "loginLoginPassword">
            </div>
            <input type= "submit" value= "Login" class= "signup-confirm">            
        </form>
```

As you can see, its a simple form that is sent to `login.php` though `POST`. Upon submitting this form, it calls a JavaScript (using jQuery) function known as `loginCheckIncorrect()`, which is shown below:

```
function loginCheckIncorrect() {
    "use strict";
    var loginLoginUsername = $("#login-login-username").val(), loginLoginPassword = $("#login-login-password");
    alert("test1");
    $.post('usernameIncorrect.php', {'loginLoginUsername': loginLoginUsername, 'loginLoginPassword': loginLoginPassword}, function (data) {
        $("#login-error-exists").html(data);
        alert("test2");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
    alert("test3");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, this function creates the variables to store the value of username and password entered in each textbox. It sends an alert out (debugging), and then uses a `jQuery.post` function to send the variables to the PHP file, which I will show below. It then  (is supposed to) takes the data sent back from the PHP file to echo into the error div I have in my HTML form.

It then calls an alert (more debugging) and uses a combination of `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` to (supposedly) stop the form from submitting. This is repeated after the post function.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header("X-XSS-Protection: 1");

include("connect.php");


$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["loginLoginUsername"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["loginLoginPassword"]);

echo "<script>alert('test');</script>";

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM main WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($count == 1) {
    echo "";
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
} else {
    echo "username and/or password is incorrect.";
}
?>
```

When I attempt to execute this code, the only alert it displays is `test1`. Could someone explain to me why this is, and more importantly, how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your network requests in your browser's debug panel to see if it's sending what you think it is, put some debug statements in your PHP to see what is and isn't getting hit.

In this case, I think you might be missing the `.val()` on `$('login-login-password')` just before the `alert("test1")` in your javascript.

Comment: Wow, I feel like such an idiot now. It's amazing how a small part of your code can cause your entire program to fail. Thanks, man.

Comment: Yep, that's why you trace your steps very carefully, and look for anything out of the ordinary - in this case, you would have seen that `loginLoginPassword` was always empty in the request.  As @epascarello noted, `event.preventDefault()` won't work without an event object to work with.  jQuery passes an event object as the first parameter, so just add that in: `function loginCheckIncorrect(event)`

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean. The `event.preventDefault()` worked fine for me without passing the event object in as a parameter. In fact, when I added that in, it caused an error. Why is this?

Comment: Not sure why you're getting errors, and am mobile now so I can't investigate. But it probably works because `return false` does the same thing (but isn't recommended). Also, your $.post() call won't be able to cancel the submit, because it's asynchronous, and by the time the request comes back the form will have been submitted. You may have to do some more restructuring before this will work like you want it to.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what's happening to me now. How would I restructure it so the post call will be able to stop the form for me? My next step for this is adding an if statement on whether to continue to the login.php or display the error message. Should I post that as another question?

Comment: You might be better off asking questions at [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) at this point, but another question (with some searching first) is an option too.  But basics: your options are to make the request non-async so it'll wait for the request to come back (slow and bad practice), or validate the username when they enter it (using e.g. keyup or blur events), set some flag (and probably some UI feedback), and then check that flag in the onSubmit() callback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50929/discussion-between-cincodenada-and-jaredcubilla)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `event` defined. That would be a problem and the form will submit. And the preventDefault in the callback is useless since the function already finished.

Answer (score 0):

1) The name of the php file is **login.php**

2) The url to which you are requesting the post is **usernameIncorrect.php**

Therefore:

```
$.post('login.php', {'loginLoginUsername': loginLoginUsername, 'loginLoginPassword': loginLoginPassword}, function (data) {
    $("#login-error-exists").html(data);
    alert("test2");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Alert test1 is the only one appearing because the post fails.
Probably with a fail event you would have cached the error.

Try, if you want to test that:

```
$.post('wrongUrl.php', {'loginLoginUsername': loginLoginUsername, 'loginLoginPassword': loginLoginPassword}, function (data) {
    $("#login-error-exists").html(data);
    alert("test2");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

Comment: OP seems to have a separate script (usernameIncorrect.php) which checks the username *before* submitting to login.php

Comment: "OP seems to" is subjective. Objectively, the only information we have about a php file name is "login.php" and therefore my conclusion.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion Hector. I did have a separate file called `usernameIncorrect.php`; it was the PHP code I showed you. `login.php` it's sent to after validating that the username was in the database.

Comment: Oh, no problem Jared. These things happen :) What I am not so happy about is @cincodenada's downvote.

Comment: I tried un-downvoting you but it's too late to do so now.  The downvote was mostly because you gave a definitive answer based on assumptions that weren't well-supported and ended up being faulty.  If the answer was more tentative ("Do you really have two separate PHP files?") I wouldn't have downvoted.

Comment: let's balance things up